# Do poor people, people of color, and elderly have difficulty in obtaining ID in the US?

Tags: united-states, voter-registration, identity-document, voter-suppression

As mentioned [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/70245/how-do-the-republicans-laws-make-it-harder-for-democratic-voters-to-vote) and [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/918/does-it-cost-25-to-obtain-a-free-voter-id-in-any-state) a commonly listed argument regarding voter ID's is the decreased ownership and/or difficulty in obtaining among the poor, people of color, and elderly.

A [similar](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31716/demographic-with-greatest-difficulty-in-maintaining-current-us-voter-id) question has gone without an accepted answer, with the more complete suggested answer downvoted, but doesn't answer my question.

This claim is made repeatedly that for some reason poor, people of color, and elderly have difficulty in obtaining ID to vote. Where is there source material for this?
What evidence is there that it has any significant impact outside of the homeless community?
Are there any hard facts, statistics, studies, or other material that support this claim?

Everything I've been able to find is that the only group of people that has problems with obtaining ID are the homeless. People of color, in general, seem to be able to ID themselves without much trouble.

Please note, I am **NOT** asking about difficulty in voting. This question is specific towards obtaining sufficient ID for eligible voters.

Anecdotally, I worked with programs involving unemployment, child support, TANF, SNAP, Medicaid, Medicare and a few others. At no point in 5 years working with those programs did I hear of ID being an issue. I know anecdotes are no substitute for data, but I haven't ever seen this claim supported with any real data.
I am not interested in contrived arguments regarding hypothetical situations.

Comment: If you're interested, there's this document, titled "The High Cost of ‘Free’ Photo Voter Identification Cards", which cites its sources quite a bit as far as I can tell (haven't read much of it), and, in addition to some analysis, later uses multiple anecdotes to show how it can be expensive for some.
https://today.law.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/FullReportVoterIDJune20141.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure why "outside the homeless community" is mentioned... many (most?) of the homeless are citizens as well....

Comment: If you differentiate the homeless community, it provides a clearer picture on the poor, people of color, and elderly. I'd like to avoid any intentional or incidental obfuscation of the issue. Homeless have a recognizable difference in obtaining documents than other demographics. The line blurs some between homeless and poor. However, it isn't fair to people of color to claim that they do have an issue if it turns out that the only subset of people of color with the issue end up being the homeless.

Comment: Many comments deleted. Please don't use comments to debate the question matter. If you would like to answer, please post a real answer. If you would like to discuss, please use the chat function. Please try to limit these comments to suggesting improvements to the question. Note that the top voted answer has a chat room linked in a comment.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**Do poor people, people of color, and elderly have difficulty in obtaining ID?**

## Yes.

For example, here are some facts (citations to supporting authorities are found at [this link](https://www.aclu.org/other/oppose-voter-id-legislation-fact-sheet)) (the omission of paragraphs from the source related to subjects not pertinent to the question are not expressly noted in the quoted material below).

> Anecdotally, I worked with programs involving unemployment, child
> support, TANF, SNAP, Medicaid, Medicare and a few others. At no point
> in 5 years working with those programs did I hear of ID being an
> issue. I know anecdotes are no substitute for data, but I haven't ever
> seen this claim supported with any real data.

The real data quite overwhelmingly establishes that your anecdotal impressions are inaccurate.

> 11% of U.S. citizens – or more than 21 million Americans – do not have government-issued photo identification.

Note that the source for this statistics clarifies that this is 11% of voting-age American citizens.

A demographic breakdown of adult U.S. citizens with and without photo IDs can be found [here](http://www.projectvote.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/AMERICANS-WITH-PHOTO-ID-Research-Memo-February-2015.pdf). It shows that non-whites are much more likely to not have photo ID than whites (even for high income non-whites and non-whites who are not young adults), that not having a photo ID is strongly correlated with having a lower income (especially among whites), that young adults are particularly likely to not have photo ID (especially among whites). [Another source](https://www.learningforjustice.org/sites/default/files/general/Percentage%20of%20People%20Who%20Lack%20ID_0.pdf) has a convenient chart breaking down some key data points:

[image]

> Even if ID is offered for free, voters must incur numerous costs (such as paying for birth certificates) to apply for a
> government-issued ID. Underlying documents required to obtain ID cost
> money, a significant expense for lower-income Americans. The combined
> cost of document fees, travel expenses and waiting time are estimated
> to range from $75 to $175.

The economic burden and delay make it difficult for poor people to obtain ID, and this issue empirically, is much bigger than most middle class people intuitively expect as illustrated by the large percentage of adult U.S. citizens who don't have IDs.

Young married women whose names have changed are particularly heavily impacted by these costs, and even if one can obtain a suitable ID eventually, it may be challenging to do so in time to vote in the next election (particularly, for example, if you were born and/or married outside the state where you live).

> The travel required is often a major burden on people with disabilities, the elderly, or those in rural areas without access to a
> car or public transportation. In Texas, some people in rural areas
> must travel approximately 170 miles to reach the nearest ID office.

These factors make it more difficult for elderly and disabled people to obtain IDs.

For example, I have a wheelchair dependent client in a major urban area for whom I make house calls as a lawyer, because it takes him four hours roundtrip by bus, and about an hour and a half (at a much higher cost than an Uber or taxi trip) by a specialty wheel chair transportation vehicle that is often not on time for pickups, to travel from his suburban home to my central city office which is near government offices.

> Nationally, up to 25% of African-American citizens of voting age lack government-issued photo ID, compared to only 8% of whites.

The difficulty in obtaining government-photo IDs for African-Americans is strongly suggested by this difference in percentages. Most of the difference is mediated by differences in affluence, including a much higher rate of not owning a motor vehicle, and thus not getting a driver's license (the most common form of photo ID).

As [evidence from a 2014 court case](https://dc.uwm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1184&context=eti_pubs) showed:

> In May 2014 federal Judge Lynn Adelman found Wisconsin's state photo
> ID law unconstitutional given its adverse impact on many Wisconsin
> citizens. In his 90-page decision . . . [he notes] that only 47% of
> black adults and 43% of Hispanic adults compared to 73% of white
> adults in Milwaukee County hold valid driver's licenses as do 85% of
> white adults in the rest of Wisconsin compared to 53% of black adults
> and 52% of Hispanic adults.

Some of this is due to the common discriminatory practice of not locating government offices that provide these services in or near neighborhoods where most African-Americans level, or of understaffing those offices so that delays are longer.

An [NPR story](https://www.npr.org/2012/02/01/146204308/why-millions-of-americans-have-no-government-id) explores some of the reasons for the differences:

> I think the first thing to look at is to look at who actually drives.
> The most common form of government-issued ID are driver's licenses and
> so the people who are most unlikely to drive, as it is, is elderly,
> the poor, people who live in big cities, like African-Americans,
> especially young people, too, especially if they attend college. They
> may not have need for a car at the moment.
>
> And then people who are in rural areas. The other challenge for them
> is they are not near the Department of Motor Vehicles offices, etc.,
> etc. where you would get these IDs. . . .
>
> if you're someone trying to get a voter ID, you need that type of
> documentation. In order to get an ID, you often need an ID, so it
> becomes a Catch 22.
>
> MARTIN: And what about - are the states making any provision to help
> voters like this who have not previously had IDs...
>
> DADE: Yeah.
>
> MARTIN: ...to get them? Or are interest groups doing that?
>
> DADE: Well, they are. The interest groups are trying to fill in the
> void of information, where to get the IDs, what kind of documents you
> need to get them when you show up so you're not caught unawares.
>
> As far as the states go, they are issuing non-driver voter IDs. Many
> of them are for free, but the problem is, when you go to Department of
> Motor Vehicle offices, the waits are very long, they're time
> consuming. The governor of Tennessee, who's a Republican, by the way -
> he has expressed concern about the average wait times there, which
> extend well beyond an hour. And if you're talking about thousands of
> elderly, in particular, they can't wait that long.

A [study of Texas voters](https://journalistsresource.org/politics-and-government/voter-photo-id-law-research/) who tried to vote without photo IDs found some of the following issues came up:

> Texans offered various reasons why they didn’t have a qualifying ID
> for the 2016 general election. Nearly 30 percent said their IDs had
> been lost or stolen. About 11.5 percent cited work obligations while
> another 4 percent said family obligations prevented them from getting
> one.
>
> Nearly 36 percent of individuals without IDs checked the “other” box,
> many of whom indicated they had moved so their current address didn’t
> match what was listed on their IDs.
>
> Of those who selected the “other” option, 1.4 percent — 82 people —
> cited cost as the reason they didn’t have the appropriate ID.

This isn't a representative sample and doesn't include the lion's share of voters without photo IDs who don't try to vote, but it is nonetheless hard data that provides some insight.

A [meta-analysis of 31 other studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7345293/) on the topic found some key factors. The main reason people reported for not having identification was that it had been either lost or stolen. Other factors included lack of money for fees, lack of knowledge of application process, lack of competency with bureaucratic forms, the requirement of an address, and the requirements of an existing piece of identification in order to apply for additional identification.

For people who are economically marginalized even seemingly minor fees constitute a financial hardship that makes the acquisition of PID prohibitive, and sometimes they are funneled though like of sophistication to commercial fee charging services that facilitate services that the government doesn't charge for or charges much less than the service does for.

> [F]ees are charged for replacement birth certificates, and if people
> go through “third party” providers rather than state agencies to
> obtain this form of ID, additional service fees are incurred. This
> means that people who have little or no money and who are likely to
> lose or have their PID stolen . . . are further burdened with higher
> replacement fees. Ultimately, people regularly prioritize the
> immediate needs of food, transportation, or rent rather than the costs
> of replacing a lost or stolen document. Furthermore, additional costs
> are required if individuals must take public transportation or live in
> rural or remote locations and have to travel to service centers.

**Additional Burdens For Proof of Citizenship**

Also, notably, proof of citizenship is [much more challenging to marshal](https://www.brennancenter.org/sites/default/files/2021-09/Requiring%20Citizenship%20to%20Register%20to%20Vote.pdf) (usually requiring a birth certificate that many people are not currently in possession of, marriage certificates to document change of name, naturalization certificates, and/or passports), then the proof of identity needed for a photo-ID without citizenship verification such as driver's licenses or state IDs that do not require proof of citizenship:

> A federal district court that heard a challenge to the Kansas law
> noted that “the sheer number” of people blocked “evidences the
> difficulty of complying with the law as it is currently enforced.” The
> court found that more than 18,000 people who tried to register at the
> state’s motor vehicle offices were prevented from registering between
> 2013 and 2016 “as a direct result” of the state’s documentary proof of
> citizenship requirement.

This is because getting a birth certificate and linking it to your identity, or having a passport, can be cumbersome taking time, money and even legal assistance.

A [story from the Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/courts_law/getting-a-photo-id-so-you-can-vote-is-easy-unless-youre-poor-black-latino-or-elderly/2016/05/23/8d5474ec-20f0-11e6-8690-f14ca9de2972_story.html) puts flesh on the bones of the raw statistics and illustrates in personal and compelling examples, how these factors play out in the lives of individual people without photo IDs. One such story is this one from Texas:

> Many of the residents struggling to obtain a valid photo ID are
> elderly and poor and were born in homes rather than hospitals. As a
> result, birth certificates were often lost or names were misspelled in
> official city records.
>
> Hargie Randall, 72, was born in his family’s home in Huntsville, Tex.,
> and has lived in the state his entire life. Randall, now living in
> Houston’s low-income Fifth Ward neighborhood, has several health
> problems and such poor eyesight that he is legally blind. He can’t
> drive and has to ask others for rides.
>
> After Texas implemented its new law, Randall went to the Department of
> Public Safety (the Texas agency that handles driver’s licenses and
> identification cards) three times to try to get a photo ID to vote.
> Each time Randall was told he needed different items. First, he was
> told he needed three forms of identification. He came back and brought
> his Medicaid card, bills and a current voter registration card from
> voting in past elections.
>
> “I thought that because I was on record for voting, I could vote
> again,” Randall said.
>
> But he was told he still needed more documentation, such as a
> certified copy of his birth certificate.
>
> Records of births before 1950, such as Randall’s, are not on a central
> computer and are located only in the county clerk’s office where the
> person was born.
>
> For Randall, that meant an hour-long drive to Huntsville, where his
> lawyers found a copy of his birth certificate.
>
> But that wasn’t enough. With his birth certificate in hand, Randall
> went to the DPS office in Houston with all the necessary documents.
> But, DPS officials still would not issue him a photo ID because of a
> clerical mistake on his birth certificate. One letter was off in his
> last name — “Randell” instead of “Randall” — so his last name was
> spelled slightly different than on all his other documents.
>
> Kamin, the lawyer, asked the DPS official if they could pull up
> Randall’s prior driver’s-license information, as he once had a
> state-issued ID. The official told her that the state doesn’t keep
> records of prior identification after five years, and there was
> nothing they could do to pull up that information.
>
> Kamin was finally able to prove to a DPS supervisor that there was a
> clerical error and was able to verify Randall’s identity by showing
> other documents.

**Is Lack Of A Photo ID Indicative Of Being Ineligible To Vote?**

It also bears noting, while slightly off the narrow scope of the question, that the likelihood that an African-American who speaks English with an American accent (a group that makes up the vast majority, probably 98% or more of African-Americans who do not have IDs in all but a handful of counties in the United States) not being a U.S. citizen is vanishingly small.

Put another way, virtually all of the 25% of African-Americans adults without IDs in the United States are U.S. citizens who are eligible to vote (absent felony disqualification which is present mostly in states that also impose other barriers to voting like voter ID laws and also have a long history of racial discrimination). The [share of African, Afro-Caribbean, and black Latin American legal immigration to the U.S. is modest](https://www.pewresearch.org/social-trends/2015/04/09/a-rising-share-of-the-u-s-black-population-is-foreign-born/), many of those immigrants are naturalized citizens, and those immigrants overwhelmingly have passports. About 6-7% of undocumented immigrants in the United States are black (see [here](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2020/08/20/key-findings-about-u-s-immigrants/) and [here](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2018/01/24/key-facts-about-black-immigrants-in-the-u-s/)) and those undocumented immigrants are overwhelming recent immigrants.

Voters not infrequently have some form of ID but not one of the forms of ID required by Voter ID laws. The types of IDs allowed are tailored to political demographics:

> States exclude forms of ID in a discriminatory manner. Texas allows concealed weapons permits for voting, but does not accept student ID
> cards. Until its voter ID law was struck down, North Carolina
> prohibited public assistance IDs and state employee ID cards, which
> are disproportionately held by Black voters. And until recently,
> Wisconsin permitted active duty military ID cards, but prohibited
> Veterans Affairs ID cards for voting.

One particularly notorious case involves [South Dakota's unwillingness to accept Indian tribe IDs](https://thefulcrum.us/voting/south-dakota-native-american-voting), an especially big factor for people who live on Indian reservations that are remote from non-tribal government offices, who are often poor, and are a group of people that almost by definition is made up 100% of U.S. citizens.

**Selected Sources**

The sources for the fact cited above include the [Brennan Center](https://www.brennancenter.org/sites/default/files/legacy/d/download_file_39242.pdf) Brennan Center for Justice, *Citizens without Proof: A Survey of Americans’ Possession of Documentary Proof of Citizenship and Photo Identification* (New York: Brennan Center for Justice, 2006), a report from the federal government's [General Accountability Office](http://gao.gov/assets/gao-14-634.pdf) (GAO), a published academic journal article with three [University of California at San Diego](http://pages.ucsd.edu/%7Ezhajnal/page5/documents/voterIDhajnaletal.pdf) professors as authors, and a Harvard law professor's published academic article, Richard Sobel, *The High Cost of ‘Free’ Photo Voter Identification Cards* (Cambridge: Charles Hamilton Houston Institute for Race and Justice at Harvard Law School, 2014).

Comment: Although the answer does indeed mention that among African-American citizens a larger percentage doesn't have a government-issued photo ID, it doesn't mention why that is. It doesn't explain if those people have difficulty obtaining it, which is OP's question.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it would help if you provided direct references (and if possible some explanation of the methology behind the figures) rather than requiring people to click through a series of links, any one of which could break at any time, to get to the sources. (I had to follow the link to the ACLU, download a PDF, and then click on links in that PDF to get to the sources.)

Comment: This answer completely sidesteps the actual question. You quote that 25% of African Americans is not registered to vote, compared to only 8% of whites. But you do not provide any evidence that this is because the one group has greater difficulty registering than the other.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133147/discussion-on-answer-by-ohwilleke-do-poor-people-people-of-color-and-elderly-h).

Comment: Wait, your statistic of "11% of us citizens do not have a government issued ID." Is that 11% of voting-age citizens? Many US Citizens are under 18. According to my quick search, I found that 22% of citizens are under 18! that 11% figure is an alarming figure, but it would carry more weight if it were about those voting-age.

Comment: @macetw The source clarifies that it is 11% of voting age U.S. citizens.

Comment: @user41655 and IvoBeckers To the contrary this answer does describe what the barrier is (lower affluence and discriminatory access to offices that provide the service). And to Stuart, I have provided links in the body text per your request.

Comment: @ohwilleke; to say that student ID isn't acceptable for voting because most students are democrats is like saying that democrats want strict gun laws because most gun-holders are republican. Needless to say, that's not the case.

Comment: Of the 11% without government-issued photo ID, how many live in states that require photo ID to vote?  Of voting-age citizens in states that require photo ID to vote, what percentage lack it?

Comment: *Nationally, up to 25% of African-American citizens of voting age lack government-issued photo ID* How **exactly** was this number obtained? As in a step-by-step breakdown of the methodology, no handwaving. Seems highly suspect at best.

Comment: @JonathanReez The sources describe how this number was obtained. Do you have another contradictory source of data? This 25% figure is corroborated by much lower driver's license rates.

Comment: @ohwilleke I think there’s two questions: whether 25% actually don’t have any voting ID and whether they don’t have it because they don’t want it or because it’s hard to get. I’ll look into both and add my own answer over the weekend.

Comment: "The types of IDs allowed are tailored to political demographics" The quote doesn't really back this up at all. Student IDs typically aren't considered voter ID because they require almost no substantiation at all of identity to get one, whereas carry permits are typically issued by the state and have much more consistently and strictly enforced requirements for identity verification to get one. I'm not familiar with VA IDs, so I'm not sure what the deficiency with those was, but CACs for active military (or contractors) have quite strict identity verification requirements in my experience.

Comment: If anything, VA IDs not being eligible appears to be a _counter-example_ to the assertion that the requirements are "tailored to political demographics," as veterans tend to be much more likely to vote for Republicans than for Democrats. By contrast, younger active military members are significantly more likely than their older veteran counterparts to vote for Democrats.

Comment: @JonathanReez After reading source materials, the 25% is an estimate based on a poll of 987 respondents that was extrapolated out to account for racial demographics. The margin of error for this particular result, to a 95% confidence level, is ±8%. Brennen center link. Even if the result is an over estimate by triple the margin of error this would still be the lead demographic. However, I am unable to find any reasoning behind this disparity.

Comment: @DavidS it seems like a poll would be extremely biased by people potentially mistrusting the interviewer and saying they don't have an ID because they're afraid they might be asked to show it. So I wouldn't trust it. A government database should be much more reliable.

Comment: @JonathanReez But the data from driver's licenses from Wisconsin closely corroborates the survey data, suggesting that it is reliable.

Comment: @DavidS The disparity is mostly driven by lack of driver's licenses and by poverty rates.

Comment: @ohwilleke but driving licenses are not the only form of voter ID, even in the strictest states. And the ID rates are probably rapidly growing over time as more and more things require one.

Comment: @JonathanReez Certainly the driver's license isn't the only form of ID. But if you look at the survey statistics and the driver's license statistics, the percentage of people without any government issued photo ID tends to be roughly the same percentage of people who don't have a driver's license in every subcategory. There is no good reason to think that this general trend has changed much.

Comment: @ohwilleke right, but it’s also possible that people without a driving license (but with alternative ID) are also the ones more likely to give an untruthful answer on surveys.

Comment: @JonathanReez A lot of analysis done on survey respondent truthfulness following inaccurate results in the 2016 and 2020 elections both concluded that lying on political surveys is very uncommon and that differences in response rates were the main factor. A BBC report with a more dubious methodology came to the same conclusion. https://www.bbc.com/news/blogs-magazine-monitor-29206289

Answer (score 13):

It's important to distinguish here between ID in general and ID that specifically meets a state's requirements for voting, especially when the state has designed the details of these restrictions to favor or disfavor certain groups.

Many people have some form of ID which serves them well enough in daily life, but it may not be one that's accepted to vote. For example:

- [Some states](https://www.vote.org/voter-id-laws/) reject IDs that are expired, while others allow expired IDs only for seniors (as many seniors who've stopped driving no longer have much need to renew their ID and face particular burdens in doing so). This disproportionately makes it more difficult for younger people with expired IDs to vote.
- Some states accept ID issued by other states, while others accept only in-state IDs. This impacts those who have more recently moved and especially impacts students, who often don't obtain a new ID if they're attending school in another state.
- Some states accept student IDs, while others do not [or have difficult-to-satisfy requirements associated with them](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/24/us/voting-college-suppression.html) that mean many of them aren't  accepted.
- Some states require the ID to show your current address. This disproportionately impacts those who move frequently, who tend to be poorer and/or students. Some may accept additional documents if this isn't the case, but even if this is an option, students often don't have documents like utility bills or bank statements sent to their dorm rooms and/or may not know about these requirements until it is too late.

The effect of all this is that many people have forms of ID that work well enough for them in their daily lives but aren't accepted when they want to vote. This topic always brings up a lot of "how could anyone function in society without an ID?" incredulity, and yet people with multiple perfectly good forms of ID, such as a college student with both an out-of-state driver's license and a student ID, can find themselves unable to vote because their ID doesn't meet a state's particular requirements.

How does this work out in practice? [Michigan offers one example](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/michigan-agrees-to-make-it-easier-for-college-students-to-vote/2019/06/05/5a5a24c8-87c3-11e9-a870-b9c411dc4312_story.html), though they subsequently improved this process to make it somewhat easier:

> “Your registration had to match with the address on your license,” said Carter Oselett, 20, a junior at Michigan State University and the president of the school’s College Democrats. “So if someone registered at their dorm, but their license had their home address or wherever they moved from, even though they registered at their dorm, if they didn’t update their license, that would lead to them being turned away from the polls.”

Or [consider this Texas man](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/courts_law/getting-a-photo-id-so-you-can-vote-is-easy-unless-youre-poor-black-latino-or-elderly/2016/05/23/8d5474ec-20f0-11e6-8690-f14ca9de2972_story.html):

> In his wallet, Anthony Settles carries an expired Texas identification
> card, his Social Security card and an old student ID from the
> University of Houston, where he studied math and physics decades ago.
> What he does not have is the one thing that he needs to vote this
> presidential election: a current Texas photo ID.
>
> For Settles to get one of those, his name has to match his birth
> certificate — and it doesn’t. In 1964, when he was 14, his mother
> married and changed his last name. After Texas passed a new voter-ID
> law, officials told Settles he had to show them his name-change
> certificate from 1964 to qualify for a new identification card to
> vote.
>
> So with the help of several lawyers, Settles tried to find it,
> searching records in courthouses in the D.C. area, where he grew up.
> But they could not find it. To obtain a new document changing his name
> to the one he has used for 51 years, Settles has to go to court, a
> process that would cost him more than $250 — more than he is willing
> to pay.

And the nature of these requirements is that they tend to fall disproportionately on certain groups. Those with more stability in their housing situation, transportation access, and other social factors are more likely to have a valid in-state ID, while those who move frequently and/or lack time and transportation may end up with an ID that works for them for most all purposes only to be surprised it's not accepted to vote. And this disproportionate treatment may be further codified into law, such as if expired IDs are permitted for seniors but not younger voters.

Comment: The college student example seems quite odd; isn't turning away out-of-state students away *exactly how it's supposed to work?*  When I was in college we were Very Officially told, both with regards to voting and to the census, that those of us who were from out-of-state were legally not considered local residents and should behave accordingly, responding with home addresses and such on the census and voting from our home states (absentee if need be) in elections.

Comment: And the case of Anthony Settles looks even stranger.  This claim is going to ring warning bells in the heads of anybody who's ever had dealings with lawyers: all that searching he had them do certainly cost significantly more -- probably by at least an order of magnitude! -- than the $250 that's supposed to be a dealbreaker for him.

Comment: @MasonWheeler No. In general, and there may be some nuance to this in a few states, college students [are able to choose](https://help.vote.org/article/17-i-am-a-college-student-should-i-register-at-home-or-where-i-go-to-school) whether they vote from their original home address or their school address, as long as they only vote once of course. Students are also [counted at their school address](https://www.census.gov/library/stories/2020/01/student-housing-off-campus-with-parents-college-students-count-2020-census.html) if they're living there on census day.

Comment: Well, clearly a lot has changed since I was in college for the 2000 census.  The instructions were very explicit that we do *not* count as local residents.  (This despite being in one of the college-towniest of college towns, where the student body made up approximately 50% of the total population!)

Comment: @MasonWheeler It's a perennial source of confusion, but for the Census, ever since 1950, students should be counted at their "usual address" (which, for students who live near their college most of the year, would be their college address).

Comment: @MasonWheeler No idea what instructions you were given then, but the [rules were similar for the 2000 census](https://books.google.com/books?id=1ECcAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT91&lpg=PT91&dq=2000+census+college+students+home&source=bl&ots=C6bSDQ0Fwo&sig=ACfU3U2RmVZHnTdS4R8R0L70phkxiAOqng&hl=en&sa=X): "those who live away from the parental home while attending college and are 'only here during break or vacation' are to be counted at their residence at college; and students living in a group quarters (such as a dormitory or a fraternity or sorority house) are to be counted at the group quarters."

Comment: "For Settles to get one of those, his name has to match his birth certificate — and it doesn’t. In 1964, when he was 14, his mother married and changed his last name." Well, that's the state's fault, not the fault of the principles behind voter ID. They should have either updated his birth certificate, or tracked the change explicitly in a database. Also, he was able to find lawyers who would search out-of-state databases for him pro bono, but not any who would waive 1/2 hour of fees for a matter of basic civil liberties? (Not to mention, the story doesn't relate to the headline WaPo chose.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it doesn't matter that it's the state's fault, it still answers the question: yes, he has an additional challenge to obtaining photo ID. And the $250 is likely filing fees and other administrative fees that a pro bono lawyer cannot waive--see https://texaslawhelp.org/guide/i-want-to-change-my-name. While it's possible to get a court fee waiver, it's up to the whims of a judge; and that doesn't waive the fees for background checks (carried out by private third parties) or for fingerprinting.

Answer (score 10):

In a lot of cases, people within a certain demographic will be more or less likely to have certain types of ID. This can be either because their demographic makes it more difficult (or impossible) to obtain an given type of ID, or because their demographic means they simply do not need or benefit from having that type of ID.

A driver’s license is a prime example of this. There are many things in the US that do not *require* a driver’s license), so someone who has an incentive to use public transport (for example, because it’s dirt cheap compared to maintaining a car) is less likely in the US to have a driver’s license.

Consider as another example a passport. There is no need for anybody who is not traveling internationally to have a passport, and they are expensive and somewhat time-consuming to obtain here in the US (though ironically often not *as* bad as a driver’s license in terms of time requirements).

Similarly, only people below a certain income level will (legitimately) have a [SNAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplemental_Nutrition_Assistance_Program) card (because the government won’t issue them to people with a higher income level), people who don’t own a firearm probably don’t have a concealed-carry permit (they don’t need one in 99% of cases, and may not be able to obtain one without registering it to a specific firearm), people who were never in the military won’t have a military ID (for obvious reasons), etc.

And, sometimes, there may simply be some particular quirk for a given person that makes it hard for them to obtain a particular type of ID. For example, I have historically had issues with the proof of residency requirement for state issued IDs where I live because I lack most of the things they assume a ‘normal’ person might have to prove where I live and they require two sources of proof of residency. I’m *exceedingly* lucky that my state has started accepting online bank statements as proof of residency, otherwise I would have had to spend the time to either get my bank to mail me a physical bank statement, or spent the time and money to get one of certain other types of ID that they accept as proof of residence.

Comment: Very minor quibble, but this isn't quite true: "people who were never in the military won’t have a military ID." At least hundreds of thousands, if not millions, of people have or have had military IDs without ever having been in the military. I am one of those. It's very common for people who work for military contractors to have CACs, especially if they work on base as I did.

Answer (score 10):

The catch with the comparisons about how much it costs to obtain an ID, is that they are often devoid of any other information about costs. This implies that obtaining an ID (which does not have a cost of $0) is somehow disenfranchising, compared to not using any ID at all.

All states require you to register to vote. Most will allow you to register online if you have a state-issued ID (driver license, non-driver ID, etc). This means the state already knows who you are. Otherwise, you have to present documents.

From the [NY State voter registration form](https://www.elections.ny.gov/NYSBOE/download/voting/voteregform-eng-fillable.pdf)

> Verifying your identity
> We’ll try to check your identity before Election Day, through the DMV number (driver’s license number or non-driver ID number), or the last four digits of your social security number, which you’ll fill in below.
> If you do not have a DMV or social security number, you may use a valid photo ID, a current utility bill, bank statement, paycheck, government check or some other government document that shows your name and address. You may include a
> copy of one of those types of ID with this form— be sure to tape the sides of the form closed.
> If we are unable to verify your identity before Election Day, you will be asked for ID when you vote for the first time.

They're doing two checks: one for identity and one for residency. In other words, to merely register to vote, you must

1. Obtain this document (if you don't have Internet, someone must print it for you, or get a copy from a state office)
2. Have a location you consider a residence. [Homeless individuals must use the name of a homeless shelter](https://www.lwvnyonline.org/civics-education/VotingII/Your-Right-to-Vote-in-NYS-in-NYS-Homeless-Indivs.pdf)

   > The Coalition for the Homeless filed a lawsuit that guaranteed the right to vote to homeless New Yorkers, whether they are living in shelters, in welfare hotels, or
   > on the streets. All you need to do is list the address of the homeless shelter or drop-in center as your residential address
3. Have documentation proving who you are
4. Submit the document

All of these involve travel, time and some minimal cost (if not taken by the individual, then by someone on their behalf). This is, more or less, the same for every state.

Then there is public assistance for the poor, which is almost always doled out via Social Security Number. The [list for obtaining an SSN is lengthy](https://www.ssa.gov/ssnumber/ss5doc.htm), requiring two documents an in-person interview if the person is over 12. This is necessary for Medicaid, Social Security Disability, etc. Banks also tend to require one, as does the IRS. Sadly the Social Security card is not a photo ID and [not terribly secure either](https://slspublications.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Verifying-Social-Security-Cards.pdf)

> There are an estimated 47 valid versions of social security cards, making it very difficult to verify the validity of cards based on design, paper quality or security features

The TL;DR is that you are likely going to incur *some* costs trying to prove who you are to the government (federal or local), regardless of whether you want to vote or not.

## What about voting IDs?

Voter ID challenges have been going on for years. There's reason to be skeptical of high numbers of people who both wish to vote and lack a proper ID. [Crawford v. Marion County Election Board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crawford_v._Marion_County_Election_Board) had this problem

> At trial, the plaintiffs were unable to produce any witnesses who claimed they were unable to meet the law's requirements.

Justice Stevens, writing for the majority, said this

> The relevant burdens here are those imposed on eligible voters who lack photo identification cards that comply with SEA 483.[11] Because Indiana's cards are free, the inconvenience of going to the Bureau of Motor Vehicles, gathering required documents, and posing for a photograph does not qualify as a substantial burden on most voters' right to vote, or represent a significant increase over the usual burdens of voting. The severity of the somewhat heavier burden that may be placed on a limited number of persons—e.g., elderly persons born out-of-state, who may have difficulty obtaining a birth certificate—is mitigated by the fact that eligible voters without photo identification may cast provisional ballots that will be counted if they execute the required affidavit at the circuit court clerk’s office. Even assuming that the burden may not be justified as to a few voters, that conclusion is by no means sufficient to establish petitioners’ right to the relief they seek.

That number may be greater than zero, but it's hard to estimate exactly how many are truly impacted, mainly because there doesn't seem to be an enormous overlap in people who wish to vote but cannot get a voter ID. For instance, the much maligned Georgia voter ID requirement has been around since 2008. Yet [black voters in Georgia are the fastest growing segment of voters in the state](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2020/12/21/black-latino-and-asian-americans-have-been-key-to-georgias-registered-voter-growth-since-2016/)

> The number of Black registered voters in Georgia increased by about 130,000 between Oct. 11, 2016, and Oct. 5, 2020, the largest increase among all major racial and ethnic groups, according to a Pew Research Center analysis of Georgia Secretary of State’s Office data.

If this were really some form of disenfranchisement aimed at minorities, it doesn't seem to be very effective. Some other states have lowered the bar even further by [eliminating some of the steepest costs](https://www.sos.alabama.gov/alabama-votes/photo-voter-id/obtain-free-photo-voter-id)

> The Secretary of State’s office has entered an agreement with the Alabama Department of Public Health whereby a free birth or marriage certificate will be provided to the processing or issuing agent when a voter needs one of these documents in order to obtain a free Alabama photo voter ID card.

The ultimate point is that there may be folks who wind up in the category of desiring to vote and lacking an ID, but these should be taken as edge cases and works individually, rather than asserting the system as a whole is somehow aiming to disenfranchise voters.

Comment: It should be pointed out that if you have a social security number you don't need a photo ID. All you need for ID is the last 4 of your social security number.

Comment: The number of Black registered voters in Georgia increased during a period of [fairly intense grass-roots efforts](https://www.brookings.edu/blog/fixgov/2020/12/11/georgia-grassroots-groups-helped-biden-win-will-the-party-listen-to-them-on-the-issues/) in Georgia to increase Black voter turnout.  So, all this figure proves is that voter suppression (e.g. [purging voter rolls without notifying those affected](https://apnews.com/article/fb011f39af3b40518b572c8cce6e906c)) efforts were outpaced by voter turnout initiatives.

Comment: @Juhasz that article doesn't demonstrate voter suppression. It demonstrates *what one political party claims is* done for the purpose of voter suppression, a claim the other side vigorously denies and can readily explain in other terms.

Comment: @Juhasz Then why not hinder the registration drives? And why haven't these new voters had problems obtaining the necessary ID to vote? Furthermore, the ID laws have been around for *14 years*, and black voter turnout has steadily increased. In other words, more than the 2020 cycle accounts for the increase. And [voter roll update mistakes happen to Democrats as well](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/asian-america/new-york-city-board-elections-settles-lawsuit-over-voter-purge-n816941)

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily

Many facts that are given as supporting evidence don't actually prove that some people have a harder time obtaining ID.

- While some say the combined costs of obtaining ID is between 75-175 dollars, it is important to look at what's included in that estimate. How would you estimate travel fees and waiting time? And who said those fees apply to all poor people? In other words, *not all poor people are required to pay these fees.* Some might be unable to pay these fees, and something should be done about that, but these fees might well apply only to *a small percentage of low-income households.* It might be blocking *some* poor people, but not *all* poor people. It seems like the estimated fees include expenses that don't apply to everyone and are therefore misleading. An estimate is not an average, and this estimate sounds like it includes fees that shouldn't be included, like travel fees, etc. Even if it was an average, it still doesn't prove that poor people can't get ID because of these fees. An average would reflect the total paid by *all* communities, not some.
- Even if 11% of US citizens don't have government ID, what is stopping them from getting ID? *That so many Americans don't have ID does not prove that they have a hard time getting it*
- As for travel, people living in rural areas need to travel for various reasons. That's part of living in a remote location and can't be considered a difficulty in obtaining ID specifically.
- People need to meet more requirements in Texas in order to get concealed weapons permit than to get student ID https://guides.sll.texas.gov/gun-laws/carry-of-firearms. It is possible that some types of ID do not include requirements needed specifically for valid voter ID.

While facts were given, more information is needed to prove that these statistics are due to the reasons provided (namely, that the fees are too high for *all* poor people, people in rural areas can't get ID because they need to travel, etc.)

Comment: This answer feels apologism and doesn't attempt to answer why there is a disparity (indeed it even more ridiculously tries to simply dismiss the idea without explanation).

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to actually provide any evidence that poor people, people of color, and elderly people _don't_ have trouble getting ID. You've basically just listed several pieces of evidence that they _do_ have trouble getting ID, and then asked "but what if this evidence is misleading?"

Comment: I didn't give an answer outright, but the lack of real evidence seems to suggest that the answer is no. Otherwise, someone would've provided clear evidence that the requirements were made to prevent certain people from voting. The fact is that no one has done so until now.

Answer (score -1):

**NO.**

For example:

11% of U.S. citizens – or more than 21 million Americans – do not have government-issued photo identification. **The presumption cannot be made** that these ones are actively working to acquire photo identification. If they have no identification, **how do we know** they are citizens **or** that 11% of them don't?
(*This should be a logic problem in a critical thinking class.*)

Voters must incur costs such as paying for birth certificates **only if they don't have one** to apply for a government-issued ID. Applying for healthcare, welfare, a bus pass, buying liquor, driving any kind of vehicle, all resources one would expect even low-income individuals to require, **all require ID**.

Young married women whose names have changed cannot be automatically presumed to be poor due to their age. Legal name change programs begin at $29.95 and are self-documenting. Marriage licenses are self-documenting.

The elderly, or those in rural areas without access to a car or public transportation, eat, drink, and tend to life's necessities in order remain in the world of the living, usually with some form of government assistance, **requiring them to prove who they are**. I grew up without a phone inside the house until my late teens. We **always** found a way to communicate with the outside world, no matter what. There are numerous low-cost and no-cost transportation resources targeting the low-income and disabled as well.

Nationally, up to 25% of African-American citizens of voting age lack government-issued photo ID, compared to only 8% of whites for the simple fact that government-issued ID is not treated with the same priority. If it were treated with the same priority of maintaining a  cell phone **which requires ID**, wired phone, bus, car, or shoes for one's feet, that percentage would crater.
(*Another beginner's critical thinking exercise.*)

Voters not infrequently have some form of ID but not one of the forms of ID required by Voter ID laws. **Nontheless**, voting station workers, of which I have been one, tend to be under pressure to accept as flimsy an ID as an expired voting card **or even library card** by virtue of voting observers who apply tacit as well as active pressure to do so. **The real question is**, how many voters are actually turned away for lack of acceptable ID?
(*Another prime assignment for any critical thinking class worth the time to attend.*)

States exclude forms of ID in a discriminatory manner. That's because the very act of requiring an ID is a wholly justified discriminatory act by design. Texas for instance allows concealed weapons permits for voting **because they are government issued**, but does not accept student ID cards **because they are not**. **It is wrong** to refuse public assistance IDs, Veterans Affairs ID cards, and state employee ID cards **unless they do not have an identifiable photo**, which as unreliable a source as urban legend puts forth as being disproportionately held by Black voters.

Comment: Welcome to Politics! You seem to be quoting some parts from [ohwilleke's asnwer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/70253). Please note that it would be much clearer if you used quote markup using the `>` character so it's clear which parts are your own and which parts are referred from other sources. We also require attribution, so you need to make it clear which parts are quoted and from where.

Comment: I don't see why it's relevant whether the 11% referenced in the first paragraph is actively working to get an ID or not - whatever the reason, they have deemed it not worthwhile. I also don't understand the quibble with the 11% itself. That number comes from a telephone survey of American citizens with a margin of error of +/-2%. You don't need photo ID to prove citizenship, and you can get a reasonable estimate of how many have photo IDs by simply *asking them*, which is exactly what the survey did.

Comment: There are 0 source citation in this answer.

Comment: Your first two paragraphs ignore the fact that there is not one unified ID system in the US, and that depending on the requirements, quite a few seemingly strange things may be accepted as ID for a given purpose (see for example utility bills being accepted (by law) as ID for voting in Ohio).

Comment: A cell phone does not require ID. The prepaid and pay-as-you-go plans I have had in the US do not ask for ID.

Comment: I have never needed an ID to ride a bus. Also, it is physically possible to drive a car without an ID. So the fact that you are required to have a driver's license to drive does not mean that all people without an idea just don't drive.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan sources should not be required. This is a rebuttal to the logic of arguments made by others.

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to answer the question itself; it just comments on claims made in another answer, but doesn't actually directly address the original question or provide any evidence for or against it.

Comment: @Nuclear The implicit argument is that the reason why 11% of people don't have ID is because there are barriers to obtaining one. This answer is challenging that assumption by saying that it is possible that some amount of these people either can't get an ID legally or don't want to get one. Those are cases that shouldn't be considered in policy-making surrounding identification.